# Effectively sharing test doubles between separate test targets

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, frameworks, xctest

I have a workspace for an iOS application, which consists of the main application project and a couple of separate projects that build frameworks included by the main target. Each of these projects has its own separate unit test suite.

I'm looking for an efficient way to share test doubles between these test suites. Any ideas how to do it without extracting a separate test double framework, shared between test targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) (As you point out) Extract a framework containing the doubles.

or

B) Simply add the files to each test bundle. That is, they would be the same files underneath.

The advantage of B is its simplicity. One disadvantage is that, if you build each test bundle, you will end up building these test doubles twice.

Comment: I was wondering if these is some alternative to both of these, but it seems these are the only options. Extracting a framework seems a bit overkill for like 8-10 shared doubles. I'll check out both and see how it works. Thank you!